# How to open external access database with vba code and maximise

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two MS access databases (database1.mdb, database2.mdb). When I open database1.mdb, I would like to open database2.mdb click on buton, and maximase database2.mdb (to see database2.mdb on screen).

I found code on net:

```
Public Function OpenDb(sDb As String)
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
   
    Dim oAccess               As Access.Application
   
    Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")    'Create a new Access instance
    With oAccess
        .OpenCurrentDatabase sDb    'Open the specified db
        .Visible = True             'Ensure it is visible to the end-user
        .UserControl = True
            
        .DoCmd.OpenForm "mainform"    'Open a form
        .RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
     
   End With
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oAccess Is Nothing Then Set oAccess = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: OpenDb" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

When opened database1.mdb, I create event procedure (click)

```
Call OpenDb("D:\database2.mdb")
```

Database2.mdb will be opened, but stay minimized. (blinking on taskbar).

Please help.

Comment: I tested your code and works perfect.

Comment: I tested too on several pc (win7, win10, office 10, offilce 365), databese2 is opening, but stay on taskbar,  I woud like to show database2 in front of database1.

Comment: Desired behavior is exactly what happened in my test. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: @Dusko Test the codes by closing all instance of Access. I think issue is, when other instance of Access is open then it open silently and blink on taskbar.

Comment: sometimes the database1 opens to the forefront, sometimes it remains minimized :(